# Laravel: Return query with referenced columns

Tags: laravel

How do I get referenced values within a query? If I have an example `cities` table which has referenced columns to a `countries` table and a `states` table.

MIGRATIONS

countries

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('name');
            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();

            $table->index('state_id');
            $table->index('country_id');
        });

        Schema::table('cities', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('state_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('states')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('country_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('countries')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

states

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('name');
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->index('country_id');
        });

        Schema::table('states', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('country_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('countries')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

cities

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('name');
            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->index('state_id');
            $table->index('country_id');
        });

        Schema::table('cities', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('state_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('states')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('country_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('countries')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

MODELS

country

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(State::class);
    }

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }

    protected $table = 'countries';
}
```

state

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class State extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }

    protected $table = 'states';
}
```

city

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }

    protected $table = 'cities';
}
```

OUTPUT

If I query for all cities `City::all()` I might get something back like:

```
all: [
       App\City {#3157
         id: 1,
         name: "New York",
         state_id: 1,
         country_id: 1,
       },
       App\City {#3158
         id: 2,
         name: "Dallas",
         state_id: 2,
         country_id: 1,
       },
       App\City {#3159
         id: 3,
         name: "Miami",
         state_id: 3,
         country_id: 1,
       },
     ],
   }
```

How would I return:

```
all: [
       App\City {#3157
         id: 1,
         name: "New York",
         state_id: "New York",
         country_id: "USA",
       },
       App\City {#3158
         id: 2,
         name: "Dallas",
         state_id: "Texas",
         country_id: "USA",
       },
       App\City {#3159
         id: 3,
         name: "Miami",
         state_id: "Florida",
         country_id: "USA",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: do you have the model relationship set up?

Comment: @AndySong I have added other migrations and the models

Comment: check my answer to see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the correct relationship setup, you should be able to do something like this.

```php
City::with('country:id,name', 'state:id,name')->get();
```

Here I assumed that there are PK `id` and `name` columns for both `country` and `state` tables.

The relationship should something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
    }

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
    }
}
```

Comment: this is seems to do the trick... are you able to chain the `with` function to get table data that is linked to say the country table?

Comment: @matthias yes do you mean something like `City::with('country:id,name', 'state:id,name')->where('name', 'New York')->get();` is it what you mean?

Comment: my example is not a good one... but Image that `countries` referenced a table `continents`. How do I get continent name to show on the row as well?

Comment: @matthias it's the same thing, it's still one to many with countries , just keep adding it if you want. `City::with('country:id,name', 'state:id,name', 'continent:id, name')->get();`